# What is your preferred pattern for using Qt Model-View Architecture?

Tags: c++, qt, architecture, qt4

how  do you use MV in Qt? I've tried these two approaches:

1. If there is an **existing/legacy
   code** "data"-classes, I use model
   as a facade. The
   Model-implementation class gets a
   reference to data, and calls its
   functions on model-item access
   calls.
2. For **new implementations** I derive
   the data class from QAbstractModel.

Is there any other way you do it?

Comment: FWIW, this is similar to how I do things.  1) If there is existing code that uses *Widget classes, leave it alone unless it needs an overhaul in functionalty.  2) If there is an existing/legacy code data classes, use the model as a facade.  3) If I need a new implementation, how much is related to the data inherently?  If a good amount, I create a data class and use the model as a facade, so that the methods are generally separated from the UI details.  4) Else derive from QAbstractModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I ended up taking is similar to the one you suggest.  I am currently using a facade to map between my legacy data model into the QAbstractModel.

At first the facade was a bit too complicated, but slowly I am pulling functionality out of the facade model and pushing it into my data model.  And then one day I will remove the facade completely so that my model is THE model.

Having a single model will make my head hurt less.

Answer (score -1):

The MV-code in Qt is a bit messy and feels arkward to implement. Especially if you have to implement hierarchical lists (tree views).

Depending on your need I found that using the `QListWidget`, `QTableWidget` and `QTreeWidget` convenience classes can be much less painful in some cases.

Comment: -1 Sorry, I am not asking for an alternative but for best practice with MV in Qt. Actually I don't find them messy. In contrast. All kinds of models (tree, table. list) work fine for me. Sorry, these old convenience classes are not the option in non trivial applications.